# Error : Executing command 'ant', make sure you have ant installed and added to your path

Tags: java, android, cordova, ant, ionic-framework

I am using Cordova for mobile application development.

I have installed Cordova using npm command and after the installation, I have created a cordova project. Whenever I try to add a platform (android) to the project it throws following error:

> Error : Executing command 'ant', make sure you have ant installed and added to your path

[image: Screenshot]

I have already installed `ant` on my system and configured path to `%ANT_HOME%\bin` and other respective required platforms such as `JAVA_HOME`, `ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS` and `ANDROID_TOOLS`.

Whenever I execute the `ant` command in cmd, no error's are thrown. For example, after the execution of `ant -version` command in cmd received output is:

> Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on December 23 2013.

I went through many of the questions at Stack Overflow and solved the issue of `tools.jar` not being present at JRE's `Lib` directory. still the `platform add` is not working.

Please do help me out with this. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Probably [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23299405/phonegap-platform-add-android/23299941#23299941) would help.

Comment: did you restart the command line? the environment changes only take effect after you create a new cmd window. In some configurations, it may even take a reboot (but i haven't had this since the XP days).

Comment: @Onik Thanks for your response. I have added all these paths, still it is not working. 'Ant' command is working separately, why cordova is not able to recognize the command ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At last I was able to figure out the answer of my question.

After a long day, I tried adding IOS platform for same project and I received an error code 'ENOENT' through cordova.

I did some R&D and finally found a solution at -- [Phone Gap [error] cmd: Command failed with exit code ENOENT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22312332/phone-gap-error-cmd-command-failed-with-exit-code-enoent)

Again thank you all for your precious time.

Answer (score 5):

I solved this same problem installing ant with a Windows installer contribution

https://code.google.com/p/winant/