# eclipse: mistake with ant

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, ant

I was following the tutorial and checked everything twice and still can't understand what can be wrong. Using eclisple, need to make an android apk.

```
C:\Users\Анна\Downloads\myapp\myapp\myapp>phonegap build android
[phonegap] detecting Android SDK environment...
[phonegap] using the local environment
[phonegap] adding the Android platform...
   [error] An error occured during creation of android sub-project.
C:\Users\Анна\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.3.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                    ^

Error: ERROR : executing command 'ant', make sure you have ant installed and added to your path.
    at C:\Users\Анна\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.3.0\bin\lib\check_reqs.js:47:27
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:213:5)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:334:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:498:12)


C:\Users\Анна\Downloads\myapp\myapp\myapp>
```

Comment: You need to install [Apache ant](https://ant.apache.org/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error : Executing command 'ant', make sure you have ant installed and added to your path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23321542/error-executing-command-ant-make-sure-you-have-ant-installed-and-added-to-y)