# Cannot add platform to Phonegap project

Tags: android, cordova, ant

I'm trying to set a phonegap project but I cannot seem to be able to add platforms to it. When I try to add android I get the following error message:

```
Error: ERROR : executing command 'ant', make sure you have ant installed and add
ed to your path.
    at C:\Users\spacitron\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\lib\check_reqs.js:4
7:27
    at exithandler (child_process.js:643:7)
    at ChildProcess.errorhandler (child_process.js:659:5)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:805:12)
Error: C:\Users\spacitron\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\create.bat: Command
 failed with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\spacitron\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\co
rdova\src\superspawn.js:126:23)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:753:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:820:5)
```

Which doesn't make much sense to me because when I run "and -version" I get the following:

```
Apache Ant<TM> version 1.9.4 compiled on April 29 2014
```

So what could I possibly be missing here?

Comment: Make sure that `Ant` is not just installed but also added to PATH. Refer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23299405/phonegap-platform-add-android)

Comment: How would I get ant's version from the command line if it weren't added to the path?

Answer (score 0):

As you error says that it can't find your ant.
You need to add path in your environment variables

```
PATH
```

;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%ANT_HOME%\bin;%ANDROID_SDK%;%ANDROID_ADB%;

(You can also add absolute paths in about command)

```
 ANT_HOME
 C:\Program Files\Java\ant\

 JAVA_HOME
 C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25

 ANDROID_SDK
 C:\Android\sdk\tools

 ANDROID_ADB
 C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools
```

Run these four commands to check every thing is setup properly

```
adb
android
javac
ant
```

Creating project command
move to the phonegap android folder.Press Shift+Right Click and select "open Command window here"

```
   create Path_to_Project Package_Name Project_Name
   create C:\Users\YourUsername\Desktop com.talha.test HelloWorld
```

Check these links for more help.[1](http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.ca/2012/11/getting-create-command-to-work-on.html),[2](http://cleancodedevelopment-qualityseal.blogspot.ca/2012/11/how-to-install-phonegap-for-android.html).